# centering x-tick labes in matplotlib with fixed number data

Tags: python, matplotlib, ticker

I am trying to create a grid where there are only 2 numerical numbers, 1 or 2 & is represented by green or red. 
My data is as follows

```
data = [[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

This is the code I am trying to use to obtain the x axis tick labels in the center

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())

# Customize minor tick labels
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5]))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(column_labels))

ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=True)
ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
```

But I end up getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfnSI.png) image where they are not centered.

Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT** - [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG77p.png) after the edit

This is the entire code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#importing necessary libraries
import csv,  os,  glob,  re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

#initializing and loading database
cwd = os.getcwd()
dbbiofilm = cwd
dbbiofilm+='/Database/Biofilm_Genes.csv'
with open(dbbiofilm,'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    row_str1 = []
    for row in reader:
        row_str1.append(row[0])
#print (row_str1)

#print(cwd)

#Converting txt files to csv files
directory = cwd
output = cwd
txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')
names = []
for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
    with open(txt_file, "r") as input_file:
        in_txt = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='=')
        names.append( os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(txt_file))[0])
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(txt_file))[0] + '.csv'

        with open(os.path.join(output, filename), 'w') as output_file:
            out_csv = csv.writer(output_file)
            out_csv.writerows(in_txt)

#Initializing the csv files
file_list = []
extension = 'csv'
file_list = [j for j in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
#print (file_list)

matrix = []

#For loop for looping through the different csv files
for name in file_list:

    #Reading each csv file
    with open(name,'r') as input_file:
        row_str2 = []
        for row in input_file:
            row_data = re.split(',|;', row) #Delimiting csv files with both , and ; delimiters
            row_str2.append(row_data[5])
    #print (row_str2)

    #(Re)Initializing loop variable
    i = 2.0
    flag = 2
    l = 0
    vector = []

    #Number-based (1 or 2) martix construction
    for const in row_str1:
        while(l < len(row_str2)):
            for var in row_str2:
                l = l+1
                if const == var:
                    flag = 1
        if (flag == 1):
            i = 1.0
            flag = 2
        vector.append(i)
        i = 2.0
        l = 0
    matrix.append(vector)
    vector = []
print (matrix)

#Initializing colour map (green & red)
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green',  'red'])
bounds = [0.5,  1.5,  2.5]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds,  len(bounds)-1)

#Initializing of plot
fig,  ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(matrix,  cmap=cmap,  norm=norm)

#Construction of colour bar and legend
cbar = plt.colorbar(im)
cbar.ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
for j, lab in enumerate(['Present',  'Absent']):
    cbar.ax.text(.5, (2 * j + 1) / 4.0, lab, ha='center', va='center',  rotation=270)
cbar.ax.get_yaxis().labelpad = 15
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Status of Gene', rotation=270)

#Grid construction
ax.grid(which ='major',  axis = 'both',  linestyle = '-',  color = 'k',  linewidth = 2)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, len(matrix[0]), 1));
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, len(matrix), 1));

#Labelling the axes
column_labels = row_str1
row_labels = names

# Hide major tick labels
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())

# Customize minor tick labels
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5]))
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(column_labels))
#
#ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels('') #Clears current labels
x_ticks = [i + 0.5 for i in range(len(column_labels))] #This list creates new positions of your x_labels
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks, minor=True) #Sets new labels positions
ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=True)
ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)

plt.show()
```

[This](https://github.com/vinaysb/Gene-Presence-or-Absence-with-2D-Grid) is the github code for the code with sample files

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of the issue when asking questions here. I have the impression that you're trying to plot a matrix of strings here instead of numbers, but the code is much too long and requires external input files, so I cannot test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ax.set_xticklabels('') #Clears current labels
ax.set_xticks(range(len(column_labels)), minor=True) #Sets new labels positions
ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=True) #Sets the labels on the new position
```

Comment: No, still the same issue :/

Comment: I have updated the code a little, did you use this code alone? The updated code should change the positions of the x-axis labels starting from 0 positions and ending with the number of labels all offsetted by 0.5. Also, if you can post a working code that would be great in order for me to recreate the problem.

Comment: It made everything right aligned now, I removed the +1 as it was adding an extra column and now all the x ticks are right aligned

Comment: Oh, that is actually right, I was working with another problem guess that is where the +1 came from, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? because I can't recreate your problem.

Comment: I have updated the entire code with the github repo for the same with the sample files

Comment: Thank You so much!!

Comment: No problem my friend!